# How can I make a histogram using Python just like using R hist function

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

I'm trying to do a histogram in Python just like I did in R. How can I do it?

R:

```r
age <- c(43, 23, 56, 34, 38, 37, 41)
hist(age)
```

[image: R output]

Python:

```py
age = (43, 23, 56, 34, 38, 37, 41)
plt.hist(age)
```

[image: matplotlib output]

Comment: every plotting system produces different output, if you want output exactly like R then I suggest you stick with R...  otherwise, if you can be more specific about which aspects of matplotlib output you don't like you might have a chance at getting an answer

Comment: Excellent approach + great Q. Having a strong understanding of how to execute something in one language will lend itself helpful to learning how to do it in another.

Answer (score 3):

The difference here is caused by the way R and matplotlib choose the number of bins by default.

For this particular example you can use:

```py
age = (43, 23, 56, 34, 38, 37, 41)
plt.hist(age, bins=4)
```

to replicate the [R-style histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kktVi.png).

### General Case

If we want to have matplotlib's histograms look like R's in general, all we need to do is replicate the binning logic that R uses. Internally, R uses [Sturges' Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Sturges'_formula)* to calculate the number of bins. matplotlib supports this [out of the box](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist), we just have to pass 'sturges' for the bins argument.

```py
age = (43, 23, 56, 34, 38, 37, 41)
plt.hist(age, bins='sturges')
```

<sub><sub>* It's a little bit more complicated internally, but this gets us most of the way there.</sub></sub>

Answer (score 2):

In short, use `bins="sturges"` in the `plt.hist` call.

---

From [`numpy.histogram_bin_edges`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram_bin_edges.html#numpy.histogram_bin_edges)

> `bins`:
>      [...]
>      `‘sturges’` 
>         R’s default method, only accounts for data size. Only optimal for gaussian data and 
>         underestimates number of bins for large non-gaussian datasets.

So you will get a histogram similar to `R`'s via

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

age = np.array((43, 23, 56, 34, 38, 37, 41))

plt.hist(age, bins="sturges", facecolor="none", edgecolor="k")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note however that the edges are still the minimum and maximum of the data. There is no way to automatically change this, but you could the bins manually to be exactly those from the `R` diagram via `bins=(20,30,40,50,60)`.